# index true or false statements from json code to python code

Tags: python, json, indexing

I have a json statement that i need to index. i only want to index two parts: "infected" and "result" I want to index the True or False statement along with the result which is the file name. I want the file to be a python index

json file

```
{
  "tendersearch": {
"infected": true,
"result": "EICAR-AV-Test",
"engine": "5.27.0",
"database": "5.31",
"updated": "20160920"
 }
}
```

---

current code

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
 pprint(data)
```

i just want a list of true and false by the result name.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use the json to create a dictionary?  For example, do you want the result from your sample data to be {"EICAR-AV-Test": True}?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Python index"?

Comment: acn3 - yes a dictionary, i want to easily be able to find any file that has false attached to it. it will be multiple files being scanned so i need a better way to organize and find the file and the true/false statement attached.

Comment: such as append then index, Selcuk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data takes the form:

```
{
    "keyword1":{
        "infected": False
        "result": "Name"
        "otherParams": "otherVals"
    }

    "keyword2": {
    ...
    }
}
```

When you import data from a `json` in python, it is converted to a dictionary.  This means you can traverse it as you would a dictionary to extract the information that you actually want.

For example, if you want to create a new dictionary mapping the `result` parameter to the `infected` parameter for each entry in the `json`, you can do this pretty easily by traversing the dictionary.  It is as easy as this:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

goal = {}
for key in data.keys():
    result = data[key]["result"]
    infected = data[key]["infected"]
    if result not in goal:
        goal[result] = infected
    else:
        print("Repeated result key of '" + result + "'")

print(goal)
```

For the example file you gave, this would output:

```
{'EICAR-AV-Test': True}
```

which I believe is what you want.

This method simply goes through each entry in the `json` file and creates a new `key => value` pair in an output dictionary mapping the entry's `result` parameter to its `infected` parameter, as well as quickly alert you to any errors.

I believe that this was your goal, but let me know if this does not fully answer your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisX I'm glad to have helped.  If this post fully answers your question, you might consider accepting it as the answer to help others with a similar problem.